# How to invoke search field in OPA5 tests

Tags: automated-tests, qunit, sapui5

My view contains a [`sap.m.SearchField`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SearchField.html).

How can I invoke the search in that field? The usual `trigger("tap")` approach does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I found out that a combination of the pseudo events `saptouchstart` and `saptouchend` triggered in the magnifying glass icon within the search field works.

```
return this.waitFor({
    id: "mySearchField",
    viewName: sViewName,
    success: function (control) {
        var event, searchIcon;

        event = jQuery.Event( "saptouchend" );
        event.originalEvent = event; // would otherwise cause NPE at some point in SAP code
        searchIcon = control.$().find("div[id*=mySearchField-search]");
        searchIcon.trigger("saptouchstart").trigger(event);
    },
    errorMessage: "Search field not found"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with the following one-liner ([source](https://scn.sap.com/message/15750349)):

```
    $(theSearchField).trigger("onSearch");
```

But maybe this is only possible with a more recent version of UI5 than the one used by you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution approach would be to use an [*EnterText action*](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.test.actions.EnterText.html), which not only enters the search term (*"foobar"* in the following example), but also triggers the search afterwards:

```
this.waitFor({
    id: "mySearchField",
    actions: [ new sap.ui.test.actions.EnterText({ text: "foobar" }) ]
});
```